# onclick css - border radius doesn't work

Tags: css, button, menu, border, radius

On http://www.backyardbiologics.com I have changed the css of the menu bar to a border radius:

```
#header-v4 #navigation ul#nav > li.current-menu-item > a,
{border-top-left-radius: 8px;
 border-top-right-radius: 8px; }
```

On hover, the border radius works fine. But on click, the border radius is gone and the button turns into a square again. Is there any way i can change this in css? or is this a javascript that needs tweaking?

Comment: Does the `li` still have the `current-menu-item` class on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS

```
#header-v4 #navigation ul#nav > li > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

This should fix it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
    #header-v4 #navigation ul#nav > li.current-menu-item > a:active,
    {
     border-top-left-radius: 8px;
     border-top-right-radius: 8px; 
    }
```

Add `:active` ,this selector is used to select and style the active link.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, it keeps going back to a square on click

Comment: @user3354767 can you show also your onclick function for your <li>?

Answer (score 1):

You can use such css. It works for me

```
{
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px; 
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```